# Azure Data Factory Pass "Object api name" of Salesforce Tables as Parameter from ForEach

Tags: dynamic, foreach, salesforce, parameter-passing, azure-data-factory

I trying to load some tables from **Salesforce**, the number of tables can change from time to time. We created a CSV file on a blob storage which contains the name of tables that we want to load from Salesforce, this CSV contains one column as shown bellow:

[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbtVa.png)

I have created a **Lookup activity** that refers to the CSV file (and I disabled the option of First row only), then I connected it to a **ForEach activity** which iterates over each row of the **Lookup activity**, as shown bellow:

```
@activity('TablesLookup').output.value
```

Inside the Foreach I have created a **Copy Data activity** which has **Salesforce as data source**.

The problem here is that I'm trying to **pass the table name** of the Salesforce data source (the **Object api name**) as a parameter from the ForEach. But I didn't find the option where I can **pass the table name**. Details on the figures bellow:

[Salesforce Dataset - Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhbdh.png)

[Salesforce Dataset - Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcJaj.png)

[ForEach - Copy Data, Salesforce Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i37K6.png)

This gives me an the following error:

```
ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (120) SOQL_FIRST mode prepare failure: SOQL error: [Microsoft][SQLEngine] (31480) syntax error near 'SELECT *<<< ??? >>> FROM "Student"'. SQL error: [Microsoft][SQLEngine] (31740) Table or view not found: Deloitte..Student,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (120) SOQL_FIRST mode prepare failure: SOQL error: [Microsoft][SQLEngine] (31480) syntax error near 'SELECT *<<< ??? >>> FROM "Student"'. SQL error: [Microsoft][SQLEngine] (31740) Table or view not found: Deloitte..Student,Source=Microsoft Salesforce ODBC Driver,'
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Lookup activity's output is like this:

[image]

You need to change `@item()` to `@item().Names` when you pass your value of Table Name from Look up activity's output to parameter named 'tableName' in dataset(In 'ForEach - Copy Data, Salesforce Data Source' step).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will check and get back to you!

Comment: You are welcome. If you have any doubt, feel free to ask.